# Site being cloned or deploy to domain I don't own

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I'm deploying a Rails app to EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk. I just found out, while doing a search in google that whenever I deploy to my domain, my site seems to also get deployed to a domain I don't own. I use Route 53 for my DNS as well.

Has anyone ever run into this situation or have any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a simple DNS issue. Someone's DNS A record is pointing to the ip address of your EC2 instance

Amazon recycles ip addresses. It is possible that your current ip address was allocated to someone else earlier, and they have not deleted their DNS entry when releasing the ip address.

you can run ping command to confirm both domain names resolve to same ip address

```
ping domain1.com
ping domain2.com
```